# How to pass query string to POST request in webapi

Tags: c#, webapi

I want to change GET request in WebApi to POST request because the query string which I am sending is too big and even using maximum string length still I am getting 404 error .
So I am sending the search query across in the body as opposed to the URI where I am facing issues, here ODataQueryOptions object is not getting populated from POST method. The POST request now looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetSession([FromBody] ODataQueryOptions<SessionModel> queryOptions)
    {
        return executeMethodA<DataBaseSessionResult, SessionModel>(
            () => sessionController.GetData(User, queryOptions),
            (resultObj) => FilterTranslator.ConvertTimeFormat(resultObj.Return.Data),
            (resultObj) => resultObj.Return.TotalRecords,
            (resultObj) => resultObj.ErrorCode);
    }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to populate the query options from the body of the request as opposed to from the URI. To this point I haven't been able to get the ODataQueryOptions parameter to populate from the request, and the parameter results in being 'null'. If I remove the '[FromBody]' attribute, the query options object will populate correctly from the request URI, but the same URI length issue remains.

We are using Devextreme components that create Ajax calls by default. So by default the content type is set as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Below is the code where I pass API method request as POST, if that helps and add more clarity to teh problem

```
        public static ODataSourceBuilder ConfigureOData(this ODataSourceBuilder odsb, string url)
        return odsb
               .Url(url)
               .Version(4)
               .BeforeSend("function(e) { e.method = 'POST'; }")
               .OnLoading("function(e){ onDataLoading(e); }")
               .OnLoaded("function(e){ onDataLoaded(e); }")
               .ErrorHandler("function(e){ onErrorOccured(e); }");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how are you submitting your data?

Comment: I have updated bit more details to the original question. We are using devextreme controls and this ajax call is for datagrid for which devextreme generates the ajax call indirectly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it is a problem from the client-side, Are you using some javascript framework? and if that is true, you should make sure you have the correct headers configuration for your requests,
for example the content-type application/json

Comment: Hi, when you give an answer try to provide clear steps to follow and a simple and direct explanation of the problem and its causes. You should avoid making questions and give a very general answer, you must try to be concise, simple and clear.

Comment: I have updated bit more details to the original question. We are using devextreme controls and this ajax call is for datagrid for which devextreme generates the ajax call indirectly